# How to search for :) in Solr

Tags: solr

How does one search for specific punctuation in Solr, such as `:)`? I have tried URL encoding the text but I still get this message:

```
org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse ':': Encountered " ":" ": "" at line 1, column 0.
Was expecting one of:
<NOT> ...
"+" ...
"-" ...
<BAREOPER> ...
"(" ...
"*" ...
<QUOTED> ...
<TERM> ...
<PREFIXTERM> ...
<WILDTERM> ...
<REGEXPTERM> ...
"[" ...
"{" ...
<LPARAMS> ...
<NUMBER> ...
<TERM> ...
"*" ...
```

Additionally, I need to perform this search on a text field, not on a string field. How should I configure the analyser to save punctuation?

Note that [searching google](https://www.google.com/search?&q=smiley+solr+-%22david%22+-%22D.+Smiley%22+-%22shawn%224) for the subject is impossible due to two prolific Solr contributors with the name "Smiley"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What configurations you have for the text field?
You should take care the splitting is not happening on the puntuations e.g. if using StandardTokenizerFactory or word delimiter filter.
You can define a custom field with WhitespaceTokenizerFactory or KeywordTokenizerFactory and have further filters like lower case on it.

Also, There are some characters which Solr/Lucene uses for some operation e.g. + - ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? :
You would need to escape the special characters with backslash. Check [Escape Special Characters](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters)

Comment: Thank you, the WhitespaceTokenizerFactory might help here. I am surprised that there is no `\b` word boundary tokenizer, to catch i.e. `lol:)` as two tokens `lol` and `:)`. At least no such thing is mentioned in the [list of analyzers](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilter).

Comment: not sure. but you can check PatternTokenizerFactory which can help you split words and chars.

Answer (score 1):

instead of :) search for "\:\ )" , both chars :,) have special meaning in SOLR.
for all special operatos you need to escape by prefixing with '\' char .

Comment: Thank you. I am not trying to see how to get Solr to actually index smileys and such.